# python socket argument

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have some problem in python's socket.
I would like to write a class about sync_file,and these are what I wrote.

```
import socket
class sync:
    def send_file(path,Socket):  #I would like to income two argument. First one is the file's path, and the second one is the socket object.
        f = open(path,"rb");
        line = f.read()
        f.close()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a = sync()
a.sendfile(file,s)
```

I thought I could send socket object as a argument, but it shows a error message.It said that expecting number of argument is two, but I send three.
I wonder why it happened.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing at all to do with sockets. You're defining `send_file` as an instance method; it will therefore always be passed a reference to the instance itself as the first argument.

If you want to keep it as an instance method, the signature should be:

```
def send_file(self, path, Socket):
```

You could also make it a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def send_file(path, Socket):
```

which will make it available to be called like an instance method (as you're doing), but not pass the instance as a parameter.

However, it's unclear why you're creating the `sync` class at all, since you don't appear to be using it as an object to encapsulate data, but merely to hold a single method that doesn't care about what instance it's a member of. Why not just make `send_file` an ordinary function?

Comment: About your question,thats because this is only part of my code.I have other method that I didn't write it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `self` argument for the method:

```
class sync:
    def send_file(self, path, socket):
      # ...
```

For method calls, Python automatically passes the object as first argument, so your function gets three arguments but only expects two.  Hence the error.